# return data in AngularJS' $q promise

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angular-promise

I'm trying to run a sequence (one at at time, not in parallel) of promises for http GETs.  Think of submitting a cooking recipe and the server will only accept one step per HTTP request.  And they have to be sent in order or the pie will be a mess.  And the last step is the only one returning data (a hot apple pie).

I have created a Plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/yOJhhw?p=preview

We'll start with the controller

```
angular.module("app")
  .controller("sequencialCtrl", ["$scope", "seq", function($scope, seq) {
```

The controller starts with a list of steps represented by library files so they will take >0 time to d/l.

```
    var recipeSteps = [
      'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js',
      'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js',
      'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.js'
    ];
```

Then I create a inters scope variable to display the first 80 chars of the retrieved js files for testing purposes only.

```
    $scope.inters = seq.intermediates;
```

Then I try to call the factory provided promise.  This crashes in the console at the then

```
    // the console shows that seq.submitRecipe is undefined
    seq.submitRecipe.then(function(data) {
      $scope.results = data;
    });
  }]);
```

Now the Factory

```
angular.module('app').factory('seq', function($http, $q) {
```

and we create intermediates and submitRecipe

```
  var intermediates = ['test1', 'test2'];
  var submitRecipe = function(theSteps) {
    var deferredRecipe = $q.defer();
    var deferredPromise = deferredRecipe.promise;

    deferredPromise
      .then(function() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var promise = deferred.promise;
        $http({
          method: 'GET',
          url: theSteps.shift()
        }).then(function(response) {
          intermediates.push( response.data.substr(0, 80) );
          deferred.resolve(response.data.substr(0, 80));
        });
        return promise;
      })
      .then(function() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var promise = deferred.promise;
        $http({
          method: 'GET',
          url: theSteps.shift()
        }).then(function(response) {
          intermediates.push( response.data.substr(0, 80) );
          deferred.resolve(response.data.substr(0, 80));
        });
        return promise;
      })
      .then(function() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var promise = deferred.promise;
        $http({
          method: 'GET',
          url: theSteps.shift()
        }).then(function(response) {
          intermediates.push( response.data.substr(0, 80) );
          deferred.resolve( "Apple Pie");
        });
        return promise;
      });
```

As noted before I only want to return the data from that last then which is "Apple Pie".

We close out the `submitRecipe`function with...

```
    // if this resolve isnt here, nothing is execute
    deferredRecipe.resolve();
    $rootScope.$apply();
    return deferredPromise;
  };
```

I have found that if I dont have that resolve() the `then`s aren't run.

And finally we expose our factory's methods.

```
  return {
    submitRecipe: submitRecipe,
    intermediates: intermediates
  };
});
```

At the end of the day I would like $scope.results to be "Apple Pie".

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/4nEcCbY02vh3d16EeHVF?p=preview)

There were a couple of edits which had to be made:

`submitRecipe` is a function, so you call it in this way:

```
seq.submitRecipe(recipeSteps).then(function(data) {
  $scope.results = data;
});
```

Then you may remove the unnecessary `$rootScope.$apply()`:

```
deferredRecipe.resolve();
// $rootScope.$apply();
return deferredPromise;
```

Comment: Thanks, Avijit.  That got things executing.  However, we still aren't getting "Apple Pie" out of the factory and into the controller.  Any ideas there?